# The sound of bells near the end of Breaking the Waves

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-the-waves

There is a strange scene at the end of the movie, where people on the oil rig look in amazement at some bells hanging from... what is happening here? Given the seriousness of the movie, it would be strange if this was just meaningless non-sense.

Answer (score 3):

As I remember, the heroine belongs to a chilly, oppressive Christian church which specifically forbids the ringing of bells even on special occasions.  The movie views her as a kind of saint or martyr who suffers willingly for her disabled husband and finally offers her life by submitting again to the men on the sea.  So when she dies, the ringing of giant bells shows that she has risen above that religious oppression, perhaps to heaven.